# Generating a sound with pitch like Sin[2Pi t] as t steps from 0 to 1

Tags: sound

I am trying to generate a sound with pitch that goes up and down like a sine wave from `0` to `2Pi`. So the pitch should be `Sin[2Pi t]` as `t` steps from `0` to `1`. I thought the way to do this would be somehow in pseudocode like make

```
f = Integrate[E^(Sin[x] + 2), x];
```

And then

```
Play[Sin[f[t]], {t,0,2Pi}]
```

But it seems *Mathematica* can't integrate `E^(Sin[x] + 2)`?

So then I just fooled around and did

```
Integrate[(Sin[t] + 2), t]
```

> ```
> 2 t - Cos[t]
> ```

```
Play[Sin[(1.2^(2 t - 1 Cos[t])*1000)], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

and it doesn't do what I want either...

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic approaches. In one, you define the data that will be played as a list, in the other, you define a function and Mathematica fills out the list. To define things directly:

```
t = Range[100000]/11025;
f0 = 200;
wav = Sin[2 Pi (f0 + 10 Sin[2 Pi t]) t]; 
ListPlay[wav, SampleRate -> 11025]
```

[image]

Variable `t` defines the time, 11025 is the (arbitrarily chosen) sampling rate, `f0` is the center frequency, and the inner `Sin` gives the frequency modulation.

To let Mathematica make the decisions, you can use `Play` instead of `ListPlay`:

```
Play[Sin[2 Pi (200 + Sin[2 Pi 5 t]) t], {t, 0, 4}]
```